# Load link to external website in href tag

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a column in database that hold links to websites its name is "link"
in my razor view I need to read what is found in this column in an anchor tag
so if the column hold `"www.website.com"`

```
<a href="@Model.link">click</a>
```

I expect this to result

```
<a href="www.soukcom.com">click</a>
```

but when I click on it it link me to

```
http://localhost:11767/en/Home/www.soukcom.com
```

How can I linked to the correct website link that found in database

Comment: The links are stored in your database exactly in this format "www.website.com" ?  They don't have a "/" before them?

Comment: have you tried setting the href to have the http:// in it?

Comment: see if this helps, first check if the address is correct in your database, update your addess with `http://` at start something like http://www.example.com

Comment: @maccettura yes the don't have a "/" before them

Comment: Does your anchor tag have a preceding "/"?

Comment: No i just use href=@Model.link which should be the data found in database

Comment: Can you right click in the browser > inspect element and tell us exactly what is displayed in the `href` property

Answer (score 3):

Is there any chance that you have a leading `/` character at the beginning of your `Model.link` property? If so - this would cause Razor to see this as a relative path and would explain why it's pointing to that specific location.

If you are pulling these values from a database, then you might want to consider sanitizing any relative URLs within your ViewModel by using something like the following :

```
public string NonRelativeLink => link.TrimStart('/');
```

Then simply use this updated property :

```
<a href="@Model.NonRelativeLink">click</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is update the address to an HTTP(S) Protocol

Enjoy coding !